# Looking to convert a json file into a csv file using Golang

Tags: json, go

I am trying to take the data in the "carrier.json" file and create a CSV file using Go with the information.  However, I am receiving the follow error/notice

```
./carrier_json.go:53:48: obj.APIVersion undefined (type Json has no field or method APIVersion)
./carrier_json.go:53:69: obj.CarrierSid undefined (type Json has no field or method CarrierSid)
./carrier_json.go:53:85: obj.AccountSid undefined (type Json has no field or method AccountSid)
./carrierlookup.go:12:6: main redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at ./carrier_json.go:31:6
```

I have searched online for several hours and any help would be much appreciated.  Note, I am not very technical.

The "carrier.json" has the following,

```
{
    "Message360": {
        "ResponseStatus": 1,
        "Carrier": {
            "ApiVersion": "3",
            "CarrierSid": "c7e57a2a-92d7-0430",
            "AccountSid": "2f4ce81a-f08d-04e1",
            "PhoneNumber": "+19499999999",
            "Network": "Cellco Partnership dba Verizon Wireless - CA",
            "Wireless": "true",
            "ZipCode": "92604",
            "City": "Irvine",
            "Price": "0.0003",
            "Status": "success",
            "DateCreated": "2017-10-13 18:44:32"
        }
    }
}
```

I have a go file called carrier_json.go that has the following information.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

type Json struct {
    Message360 struct {
        ResponseStatus int `json:"ResponseStatus"`
        Carrier        struct {
            APIVersion  string `json:"ApiVersion"`
            CarrierSid  string `json:"CarrierSid"`
            AccountSid  string `json:"AccountSid"`
            PhoneNumber string `json:"PhoneNumber"`
            Network     string `json:"Network"`
            Wireless    string `json:"Wireless"`
            ZipCode     string `json:"ZipCode"`
            City        string `json:"City"`
            Price       string `json:"Price"`
            Status      string `json:"Status"`
            DateCreated string `json:"DateCreated"`
        } `json:"Carrier"`
    } `json:"Message360"`
}

func main() {
    // reading data from JSON File
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("carrier.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    // Unmarshal JSON data
    var d []Json
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &d)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    // Create a csv file
    f, err := os.Create("./carrier.csv")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    // Write Unmarshaled json data to CSV file
    w := csv.NewWriter(f)
    for _, obj := range d {
        var record []string
        record = append(record, strconv.FormatInt(obj.APIVersion, 10), obj.CarrierSid, obj.AccountSid)
        w.Write(record)
        record = nil
    }
    w.Flush()
}
```

Comment: The error message is very clear. type `Json` only has one field named `Message360`. To access eg. `APIVersion` you must access `jsonObj.Message360.APIVersio`n (provided `jsonObj` is type `JSON`).

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes.

1. `carrier.json` is an object instead of an array, but you want to Unmarshal it into `[]Json`
2. the 1st parameter of function `strconv.FormatInt` is of type `int64`, but APIVersion is of type `string`
3. obj is of type `Json`, which does not have an element called `APIVersion`. it should be `obj.Message360.Carrier.APIVersion`
4. I suppose you want to want to write multiple CSV records since `d` is a slice of Json. You should use `WriteAll` instead of `Write`, because `Write` only writes a single CSV record. (improvement: add head for csv file)

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I have made the changes and now I am running into the following error: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []main.Jso

Comment: I was able to get it to work.  I appreciate your help.